# Angular template driven form is altered after some controls are added/removed

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material

A fieldset contains an adjustable number of 'select' drop down lists, and a button after each, except the last, to suppress it.
A selection on the last select control adds a new select control to the list.

```html
    <div *ngFor="let data of DataSet; let index=index">
      <div class="demo-body-action">
        <mat-form-field class="demo-body-action-formfield" appearance="outline">
          <mat-label *ngIf="data!==null">Update</mat-label>
          <mat-select placeholder="- Add -" [(ngModel)]="DataSet[index]"  name="{{ 'select'+index }}"
            (ngModelChange)="checkDataEntry(index)">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of Options"
              [value]="option.reference">
            {{option.name}} - {{option.reference}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button class="demo-body-action-delete" type="button" mat-flat-button
          (click)="removeResponseEntry(index)" *ngIf="data!==null">
          <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <div *ngIf="data==null" style="width:64px;height:40px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Those are binded to an array of (strings | null), the last index of the array is set to null programmatically.

See Stackblitz here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-dataset-so

The 'x' cross deletes a select input.
When the last select (which contains null) is changed, another null is pushed to the array.

For debugging, the template displays the form content in JSON, and the Javascript browser console dumps the model variable for comparison.

The problem: follow this simple sequence of actions:

1. Change the last select to another value, let's say 'Taz - A005'
2. Delete the first select "Popeye - A002" using the 'x' button on this line
3. Change the value in the last select, for let's say 'Popeye - A002' again but it fails with any other
   (Further changes to the selects will lead to erroneous display of the selected options)

At this point, the template displays an erroneous list of two items (A002 and null), whereas the UI displays 3 select controls, and the Javascript also correctly dumps those same three.

I guess this is caused by the way the selects are named, using the loop index:

```html
    <mat-select placeholder="- Add -" [(ngModel)]="DataSet[index]"  name="{{ 'select'+index }}"
            (ngModelChange)="checkDataEntry(index)">
```

Does someone know how to correct this using the template driven form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because you name your form values with the index and use the same index access the value. When you remove an item from the array the indexes belongs to values changes but the form values generated from indexes remain same. This causes the problems. There is a workaround of creating inline ids and use them in both in model and form values.

```js
export class SelectHintErrorExample implements OnInit {

  public DataSet: {
    data: string | null;id: number
  }[] = [];
  private _idProvider = 0;
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

  get idProvider() {
    return this._idProvider++;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    // omitted
    this.DataSet.push({
      data: "A005",
      id: this.idProvider
    });
    this.DataSet.push({
      data: null,
      id: this.idProvider
    });
  }

  checkDataEntry(index: number) {
    // Ensure dummy entry exists
    if (!this.DataSet.some(t => t.data === null)) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.DataSet.push({
          data: null,
          id: this.idProvider
        });
        console.log("New dataset: %o", this.DataSet.join());
      }, 1);
    }
  }

  removeResponseEntry(index: number) {
    this.DataSet = this.DataSet.filter(function(value, ix, arr) {
      return ix != index;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="demo-body-label-with-create">
    <div>
      Setup list of string data
    </div>
  </div>
  <fieldset class="fieldset" ngModelGroup="dataset">
    <div *ngFor="let data of DataSet; let index=index" ngModelGroup="{{'select'+data.id}}">
      <div class="demo-body-action">
        <mat-form-field class="demo-body-action-formfield" appearance="outline">
          <mat-label *ngIf="data.data!==null">Update</mat-label>
          <mat-select placeholder="- Add -" [(ngModel)]="DataSet[index].data" (ngModelChange)="checkDataEntry(index)" name="{{'select'+data.id}}">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of Options" [value]="option.reference">
              {{option.name}} - {{option.reference}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button class="demo-body-action-delete" type="button" mat-flat-button (click)="removeResponseEntry(index)" *ngIf="data.data!==null">
          <mat-icon>clear</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <div *ngIf="data.data==null" style="width:64px;height:40px">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<pre>Form :{{ form.value | json }}</pre>
<pre> Data :{{DataSet |json}}</pre>
```

There is an issue about using form arrays and a [discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9615) which is this workaround originated from.

Here is the working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-select-dataset-so-hysse9)

Comment: Thanks, great post. In the meantime, I fixed it simply by replacing the name expression in the HTML code {{ 'select'+index }} by a call to this function: computeName(index: number) {
    return 'name'+this.DataSet[index];
  }. This seems to work as long as there are no duplicates in the DataSet, which I guarantee by using a pipe on the options list.